# How to save for loop outputs as a list

Tags: python

mutate1:

```
       Hugo_Symbol  Start_position Tumor_Seq_Allele1 Variant_Classification
5           POU3F1        38512139                 G      Missense_Mutation
356140      POU3F1        38511502                 C      Missense_Mutation
388147      POU3F1        38511377                 A      Nonsense_Mutation
```

I tried

```
>>> startpos = np.zeros(3)
>>> for ind in mutate1.index:
...     for i in range(3):
...         startpos[i] = int(mutate1['Start_position'][ind]-1)
...         print(startpos)
... 
[38512138.        0.        0.]
[38512138. 38512138.        0.]
[38512138. 38512138. 38512138.]
[38511501. 38512138. 38512138.]
[38511501. 38511501. 38512138.]
[38511501. 38511501. 38511501.]
[38511376. 38511501. 38511501.]
[38511376. 38511376. 38511501.]
[38511376. 38511376. 38511376.]
```

However, I want startpos = [38512138, 38511501, 38511376], how should I change the current code?

Answer (score 2):

[Don't iterate over DataFrames when it isn't needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9857631). Use [`tolist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) in a list comprehension:

```
startpos = [i-1 for i in mutate1["Start_position"].tolist()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Pandas DataFrame, which is what it seems, it is bad practice to iterate through one.
There is an inbuilt pandas function called `to_list`

So just use `startpos = mutate1['Start_position'].to_list()`

To subtract one value use list comprehension `startpos = [x - 1 for x in startpos]`

Then convert the python list to a numpy array by `startpos = np.array(startpos)`